# Display to a user the selection of multiple colors in a cell of a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, background-color

I have two `DataGridView`, the first containing a list of users the other containing colors.

First `DataGridView` (**Users**)

[image: The First DataGridView]

The second `DataGridView` (**Colors**)

[image: DataGridView that contains colors]

By selecting a cell from the first `DataGridView`, the program allows you to associate a color with a user.
The association takes place using the right mouse button and selecting the color.

After selection, the user's cell becomes colored, of the selected color, using the `BackGroundColor`property.

### The problem

The problem now is that I have to allow the user to associate multiple colors with a user, so how can I visualize that the cell has been associated with multiple colors?

Do you have any graphic idea of how to accomplish this? Unfortunately, you can not associate more colors in a `Cell`, the only thing you can do is use the gradient but it does not matter to me.

Comment: _the only thing you can do is use the gradient but it does not matter to me_ Just what des that mean? a) How would you se/store a  gradient and b) is it not what you want. c) how many colors do you want to allow? 2-3 can be drawn in the CellPainting event but a larger number will not work well; instead you should display some icon to show : here is a multicolor user and display the full set of colors upon some interaction.

Comment: I think Option C could work, i will try it

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by accessing the 'CellPainting' event on the DataGridView.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        var temp = sender as DataGridView;

        if (temp.ColumnCount > 0 && temp.RowCount > 0)
        {
            // get the first cell at (0, 0)
            var cellposition = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 0, false);
            var xStart = cellposition.X;
            var yStart = cellposition.Y;
            var xEnd = xStart + cellposition.Width / 2;
            var yEnd = yStart + cellposition.Height;
            for (int i = yStart; i < yEnd; ++i)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), new Point(xStart, i), new Point(xEnd, i));
            }
        }
    }
```

This example code shows you how to paint on the Cell 1 (i.e. Column 0, Row 0), you can use this example to extend to further cells.